# Why am I getting low res photos when taking pictures using an app in android?

Tags: android, camera

When I'm taking pictures using the camera functionality in my app, it's returning a low res image even though the camera preview is a good resolution. My code for calling the code is:

```
final Button takePicButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePicButton);
    takePicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    });
```

My code for the activity result is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` will return a `thumbnail` (low resolution) pic

Solution : 
 you need to use the `URI` mechanism (path to image file) and query the `MediaProvider` to fetch the full resolution image

[`Save the Full-size Photo`](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Comment: There is no "URI from result". You provide the `Uri` via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, as is show in the documentation that you linked to.

Comment: The uri need to be specified on the cameraIntent. but even though,  starting the the camera with  ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE , will always use the camera settings already saved on the camera, for example if the user lunched a camera application wich used low resolution, even if you specify the uri you will get always low resolution

Answer (score 0):

Starting the the camera with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE , will always use the camera settings already saved on the camera, for example if the camera is setted out on  low resolution (the user's config, use of another camera app ..) , even if you specify the uri you will get always low resolution.

So you have two options:

- Build you own camera activity  and set its setting to high resolution
- Ask the user to set the camera resolution manually before  starting the capture

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
Bitmap picTaken = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
```

use this function to get image from URI

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getActivity().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
    if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
        fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
    }
    return null;
}
```